# Unable to return value

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to spring. Here is my code to return the values from the Access DB file I need to catch the response in my return.

I tried it in different ways nothing is liking it.

Unable to catch the return from the output of the below code.

I'm running it in my Jdeveloper.

Any ideas will be really appreciated.

```
    package accessdatatoebs;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class AccessClass {
        public AccessClass() {
          super();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // variables
            Connection connection = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            // Step 1: Loading or 
            // registering Oracle JDBC driver class
            try {
                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in loading"
                        + " MS Access JDBC driver");
                cnfex.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Step 2: Opening database connection

                try {

                           String msAccDB = "G:\\RMMDB\\RM.mdb";
                            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" +msAccDB; 

                // Step 2.A: Create and 
                // get connection using DriverManager class
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 

                // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement 
                statement = connection.createStatement();

                // Step 2.C: Executing SQL and
                // retrieve data into ResultSet
                resultSet = statement
                        .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_Materials");

               // System.out.println("ID\tName\t\t\tAge\tMatches");
               System.out.println("Material\tAccount");
                System.out.println("====\t========");

                // processing returned data and printing into console
                while(resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + "\t" + 
                            resultSet.getString(2) + "\t" + 
                            resultSet.getString(3) + "\t" +
                            resultSet.getString(4));
                }
            }

            catch(SQLException sqlex){
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                // Step 3: Closing database connection
                try {
                    if(null != connection) {

                        // cleanup resources, once after processing
                        resultSet.close();
                        statement.close();

                        // and then finally close connection
                        connection.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                    sqlex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return resultSet; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: your returntype is an int, yet you try to return an instance of ResultSet. How do you expect this to work? you also need an additional return statement at the end of the method

Comment: @Stultuske I completely agree with you. I knew that I'm missing out something as I'm not an expert. Can you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there no compilation error message? essential to solve compilation errors, so it would help if you posted that. ("*not liking it*" is a bit to vague)

Comment: no, because I don't know what your code is supposed to do. alter or remove your return statement, and add one that returns an int at the end of the method, or change the returntype

Comment: @Stultuske `int` will not help... its declared `void` (no `return`ed value)

Comment: @Stultuske It's giving me an error "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger in the original code it was declared as int. My comment was on the original code that was still visible in my browser, not the edited code.

Answer (score -1):

From here you can catch the result and return as list ,

And each newly added code I have explained  as a comment

```
public class AccessClass {
      public AccessClass() {
        super();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
//and In here I am trying to call Static method of AccessClass and Stream it 
          AccessClass.getResutFromDB().stream().forEach(result->System.out.println(result));

            // above line I used to java 8 stream api 
   // in here you can use simple method to do it      
  //for (Integer integer : result) {
 // System.out.println("result from databse  "+integer);
//}
      }
// Added separated method  and It return Integer List
      public static List<Integer> getResutFromDB() {
// you can see i have declared integer list
          List<Integer> addIntegerResult=new ArrayList<>();

          // variables
          Connection connection = null;
          Statement statement = null;
          ResultSet resultSet = null;

          // Step 1: Loading or 
          // registering Oracle JDBC driver class
          try {
              Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
          }
          catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
              System.out.println("Problem in loading"
                      + " MS Access JDBC driver");
              cnfex.printStackTrace();
          }

          // Step 2: Opening database connection

              try {

                         String msAccDB = "G:\\RMMDB\\RM.mdb";
                          String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" +msAccDB; 

              // Step 2.A: Create and 
              // get connection using DriverManager class
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 

              // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement 
              statement = connection.createStatement();

              // Step 2.C: Executing SQL and
              // retrieve data into ResultSet
              resultSet = statement
                      .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_Materials");

             // System.out.println("ID\tName\t\t\tAge\tMatches");
             System.out.println("Material\tAccount");
              System.out.println("====\t========");

              // processing returned data and printing into console
              while(resultSet.next()) {
// in here I have catch the result  and adding  to integer result to Integer List
                  addIntegerResult.add(resultSet.getInt(1));
                  addIntegerResult.add(resultSet.getInt(2));
                  addIntegerResult.add(resultSet.getInt(3));
                  addIntegerResult.add(resultSet.getInt(4));


              }

          }

          catch(SQLException sqlex){
              sqlex.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
              // Step 3: Closing database connection
              try {
                  if(null != connection) {

                      // cleanup resources, once after processing
                      resultSet.close();
                      statement.close();

                      // and then finally close connection
                      connection.close();
                  }
              }
              catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                  sqlex.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
//In here I am trying to return as List
      return addIntegerResult; 
      }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I compile the above code. We are getting some errors 1) Method 'add' not found. 2) Method 'stream' not found 3) Method 'forEach' not found 4) type <List> not found 5) Type <ArrayList> not found.

Comment: What could be the error , And you are not mentioned any error here , please share the error here then I will try to give you help ,

Comment: You use the Stream API, which was introduced in Java 8. But why don't you use try-with-resources, which was introduced in Java 7?

Comment: really @cassiomolin  why you can't give the answer as well , without downs voting me me  ,You can give the answer with all feature , at least share the answer if you have

Comment: @cassiomolin with the answer and show where is the problem without don't do it  , I was trying to do something here ,

Comment: I surely can post an answer later on, but I wish you could improve yours as well. For your own reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @cassiomolin okay thank dear , next time I will do my best